# Is a locally finite simplicial complex metrizable?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, metric-spaces, simplicial-complex

I was trying to give a metric on an arbitrary simplicial complex which is locally finite. Assume the space is path connected.

Naturally, one can consider a metric $d(x,y) =\inf \sum_{i=1}^{k} length(\gamma_{i})$ where $\cup \gamma_{i}$ is a path joining $x$ and $y$; each $\gamma_{i}$ belongs to a cell.

Then it would be a metric on the space, but I'm not sure if the topology derived from geometrical realization and the topology derived from the metric are equal.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to allow for the case when $x$ and $y$ are in different connected components, e.g., by taking $d(x, y) = 1$ in that case. Apart from that detail, the topology on the geometric realisation should agree with your metric topology (essentially by the design of the geometric realisation, which is intended to realise the local topology of the simplicial complex in euclidean space).

Comment: For simplicity, I added the condition of path connectedness. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several topologies we can put on a simplicial complex $\cal S$. For example

- The topology of the geometric realization $|\cal S|$.
- On the product space $I^V$, consider the subspace 
  $$\textstyle X=\{\alpha \mid \{v\mid \alpha_v>0\}\in\cal S, \sum_V\alpha_v=1\}$$
  Then the map $\sum\alpha_v v \mapsto (\alpha_v)_v$ a continuous bijection $|\mathcal S|\to X$. So the topology on $X$ is finer that the quotient topology on the realization.
- There is also the topology induced by the metric
  $$ \textstyle d(\sum_V\alpha_v v, \sum_V\beta_v v) = \sum_V|\alpha_v-\beta_v| $$

It is not to difficult to show that this metric induces the product topology on $X$. Moreover, if $\cal S$ is locally finite, then the simplices form a locally finite closed cover of $X$, so a set $A$ is closed in $X$ if it intersects every simplex in a closed set. That means the topology is actually the final topology with respect to all simplices, i.e. that of the realization $|\cal S|$.