# In “locally contractible” space, cycles are boundaries.

Tags: homology-cohomology, simplicial-complex

Assume $X$ is a locally finite simplicial complex such that any set $A$ of finite diameter in $X$ is contractible to a point in a given $R$-neighborhood $\mathcal{N}_R(A)$ of itself ($R$ may depend on $A$ but is always finite), all in the realization of the complex (assuming a metric agreeing with the simplicial structure is used, or I guess with just talking about neighborhoods of sets as approximations thereof by simplices).

> How do I show that for any cycle $c$ (in the chain complex) in $X$, $c$ is the boundary of some $b$ with $\operatorname{supp} b$ in the $R$-neighborhood of $\operatorname{supp} c$ ?

I think the steps would be to:

1. Fix a retraction from the support (?) of $c$ to a point, all lying in this neighborhood.
2. Use the simplicial approximation theorem to make it into a simplicial map…
3. Whose support will be the support of $b$, somehow.

Visually, it all seems very reasonable, but I can't very well grasp how to make it into an actual argument.
For instance, I'm troubled by the fact that a homotopy works on a set, but our chains correspond to “weighted” sets somehow, thus my inclusion of the “support” wording.

**Edit:** I want to stress out the fact that the question is not about showing that homology is zero or that $X$ is contractible, but that any homological cycle is a boundary, with control over the support of the chain which boundary we consider.

Comment: So your asssimption on $X$ is this: Each $A \subset X$ has a neighborhood $R$ such that $A$ is contractible in $R$. Correct? In that case $X$ must be contractible (take $A = X$) and you may take $R= X$ for all $A$.

Comment: No, I assume that any $A \subseteq X$ of finite diameter is contractible in $\mathcal{N}_R(A)$ for some $R>0$ depending on $A$, but this was not clear, so I'll edit the post accordingly.

Comment: So you need a metric on $X$. Then you must consider locally finite $X$. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1424424. Moreover, as in my first comment, $X$ must be contractible. If $X$ is finite, then you can always take $R = diam(X) < \infty$

Comment: X locally finite is an OK assumption, and I think I can get by without a metric by replacing $R$-neighborhoods with approximations thereof by simplexes.  
Is it obvious that $X$ must be contractible?

Comment: Yes. Consider $A = X$. The only neighborhood of $X$ is $X$ itself.

Comment: What if $X$ is infinite?
Also, are you implying $X$ contractible would answer my question?

Comment: After you added "finite diameter" as a requirement for $A$, we cannot take $A=X$ if $X$ is infinite. But if $X$ is finite, then it must be contractible, and therefore your condition is satisfied for all $A$. It is well-known that the homology groups of a contractible $X$ vanish in positive dimensions. This means that each cycle is a boundary.

Comment: Right, but the question is about constructing specific boundaries, so this doesn't answer it, or am I missing something?

Comment: Not an answer, just comments.

Comment: OK, I thought I might be missing something obvious… thanks for the comments!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my "progress" to an answer so far:

Fix some cycle $c$ of finite support $C$.
By the contractibility assumption, there exists a homotopy:
$$
H: C \times I \to B \subseteq |X|,
$$
homotoping $C$ to a point in $B$ (wlog assume $B = \mathrm{Im}(H)$).
Assuming $B$ is contractible, we would get that $c$ is the boundary of some $b$ with support in $B$, and be done (but that's using the fact that simplicial homology is equal to singular homology, somewhat…)

So I think the goal would be to show that $B$ is essentially a subdivision of a cone.

The first step is to use simplicial approximation to turn $H$ into some:
$$
H' : C' \times I' \to B
$$
with $C'$ and $I'$ subdivisions of $C$ and $I$ respectively.
Now we should check that the simplicial map $H'$ we get is still a homotopy of $C'$ to a point.

Then, what?